# Grayscale video streaming from Google Glass using WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc, google-glass, h.264, vp8

I'm trying to stream audio and video from a Google glass to a browser. The broswer just has to receive the video and audio.

I compiled the google source code following the instructions here http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android.

So far, it works. But I'm having an issue with the video. It's displaying in grayscale, and I'm not sure what are the changes that I should do on the source code in order to fix this.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]
I found two related issues in stackoverflow.com, but I didn't get the solution:

- [VP8 Encoding results in grayscale image on Google Glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049712/vp8-encoding-results-in-grayscale-image-on-google-glass)
- [VP8 encode/decode on android results in black and white image with red, green and blue squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036417/vp8-encode-decode-on-android-results-in-black-and-white-image-with-red-green-an)

Thanks very much for any help that you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the first answer you gave, you likely need to compensate for a bug in the camera code for Glass.  The image capture code probably thinks it's getting YV12, and actually is getting NV21, so the simplest thing to do is to convert NV21 to something else (like i420, which is the common internal video representation used).  Alternatively, change the frame objects to say they're NV21 and let the rest of the code handle it.

Comment: Thanks! What I did was convert the frames from NV21 to i420, and worked perfectly. Now I want to investigate if it is possible to set the format of the camera directly to i420. This way I can avoid this extra process of the CPU.